# Replace Special Character String with anotherString in Android

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem and not able to find out the answer. I want to change set of Special character in String and Replace them with another String just like below:

```
if(Text.contains("%^@&*@**&@")){

            Text = Text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("%^@&*@**&@"),"myString");

}
```

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really all you need to do

```
Text = Text.replace("%^@&*@**&@", "myString");
```

Comment: Thanks.It is working like a Charm.Only problem is that I have to put that in a loop to replace all.But Can you explain me why that happens.

Comment: You shouldn't have to put it in a loop. String.replace() "Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified character with another character." When you call String.ReplaceAll() Java expects the first argument to be a regular expression. So, you would need to escape your replacement string.

Comment: Oh.I got it I should have tried using String.replace() without that Loop before asking that.I would have go my answer.
A Big Thank To U.